# Python : Calculate difference between dates in months

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the difference in months between two dates using relativedelta. I'm able to find the difference in years and days but I get 0 when I filter on months. Any suggestions?

```
from dateutil import relativedelta as rd
import datetime as date 

dateformat = '%Y/%m/%d'
startDate  = date.strptime('2017/07/01',dateformat).date()
endDate = date.strptime('2019/10/29',dateformat).date()

date_diff = rd.relativedelta(endDate,startDate)

print(date_diff.days)
```

Comment: Please show your imports, specially if you're renaming things. Also, your example produces `relativedelta(years=+2, months=+3, days=+28)` for me, which looks totally fine.

Comment: @ tzaman my imports are the following:

Comment: ```from dateutil import relativedelta as rd  ```

Comment: ```import datetime as date```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I've edited them into your question so people can run your code more easily via copy and paste. Also, `import datetime as date` is a really bad idea, don't do that; it confuses things massively since `datetime` already contains a class named `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`relativedelta` shows the difference as years, months, and days. It's not going to show *net months* if that's what you're looking for. If two dates happen to be on the same month in different years the `months` attribute will be zero.

If you want to show the total months, you can write a small function that does that for you by adding in the years value.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def month_delta(start_date, end_date):
    delta = relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
    # >>> relativedelta(years=+2, months=+3, days=+28)
    return 12 * delta.years + delta.months

d1 = datetime(2017, 7, 1)
d2 = datetime(2019, 10, 29)
total_months = month_delta(d1, d2)
print(total_months)
# >>> 27
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month

assert diff_month(datetime(2010,10,1), datetime(2010,9,1)) == 1
assert diff_month(datetime(2010,10,1), datetime(2009,10,1)) == 12
```

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't relativedelta calculate the difference in months?

Comment: Can I replace the values (2010,10,1),(2010,9,1), etc. with the variables I created?

Answer (score 0):

end-start will produce timedelta object on which days attribute will gve the required days difference

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> start = date(2017,7,1)
>>> end = date(2017,11,11)
>>> (end-start).days
133
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought timedelta only supports days and weeks?